# Group by my json object and get the count of each group

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, rest

I am working with 2 rest api services. the first one will get items from a list named "Main category" as follow:-

```
/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainCategory')/items?$select=Title
```

and it will return the following json:-

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {                    
                "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 15,
                "ID": 15,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
                "Title": "A",
                "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
                "Created": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
                "AuthorId": 1,
                "EditorId": 1,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "GUID": "c93d9db6-efd8-4b49-9024-f8cc30c0a48e"
            },
            {
                 "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 16,
                "ID": 16,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
                "Title": "B",
                "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
                "Created": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
                "AuthorId": 1,
                "EditorId": 1,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "GUID": "a023853c-e967-4db8-8414-a7c390dcc09a"
            },
```

and i have another list named `Pages`, where each page is linked to a main category item.

```
/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items??$select=Title,MainCategory&$filter=MainCategory eq
```

here is the return json:-

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {    
                "Title": "Home",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "ewrwe",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "tgtg",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "dsdfsfdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsd",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "jk",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

now i want to show a table which show the number of pages under each category. so i implemented the following, which do the following:-

1. get all the main categories.
2. for each main category do another call to the pages list to get the related pages and count the result.

here is my script:-

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  function getCurrentMainCategoryID() {    
    var results = "";
    var html = "";
    html = "<table style='margin-left:20%;width:50%;boarder:3px solid'><th style='text-align:left'>Main Category</th><th></th><th style='text-align:left'>Pages</th>";
    var url = "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainCategory')/items?$select=Title";

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      async: false,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {    
          results = data.d.results;
          for (var j2 = 0; j2 < results.length; j2++) {    
            var currentMainCatTitle = results[j2].Title;

            $.ajax({
              url: "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items??$select=Title,MainCategory&$filter=MainCategory eq " + "'" + currentMainCatTitle + "'",
              method: "GET",
              async: false,
              headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
              },
              success: function(data) {
                if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                  html = html + "<tr><td>" + "</td>" + "<td>  </td><td>" + data.d.results.length + "</td></tr>";
                }
              },
              error: function(data) {
              }
            });
          }    
        }    
      },
      error: function(data) {
      }
    });
    $("#inserthere").after(html + "</table>");

    return results;
  }

  getCurrentMainCategoryID();
});
</script>
```

now my script will show the correct result. but i am facing a performance issue, since i am initiating a separate call for each main category.
so i am not sure if i can modify my script to do the following:-

1. get all the main categories (as i am currently doing it).
2. get all the pages at once. instead of separately getting the pages for each main category ..
3. inside the script to group the pages according to their main category. and store the results inside a temp variable
4. loop through the main category items, and for each main category item get its count from the temp variable in step 3...

so can anyone advice on this please? how i can group my json based on the main category?

Comment: how many categories are you getting ? Are too many results ? Maybe you could use paging for your table

Comment: @Gonzalo.- it is not about how many categories i have ,, it i about doing a seperate api call for each category... which is not efficient .. so i want to get all the pages using a single api call ,, and do the filter on the javascript itself

Comment: @johnG check my answer. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: If you own that API, please consider implementing GraphQL. Doing what you are asking for will become dumb.

Comment: If you are using a SQL-based data store your best bet is to get all the data in one query (using JOINs). If you use a library like [sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/) it does all the heavy lifting for you. Then you can create views and indexes to optimize this query at the db-level.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make the minimum number of ajax calls you will need to make just two, as you say (although you could do it with only one if you really, really wanted). The key is to nest them: so the success of the first triggers the second, and then the successful response of the second displays the results.

I'd do it something like the following. Here I'm just displaying the GUID from the Main Categories, and the count of the matching Pages, which, if I understand correctly, is essentially what you're after.

```js
var mainCategorySimulatedResponse = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
      "Id": 15,
      "ID": 15,
      "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
      "Title": "A",
      "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
      "Created": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
      "AuthorId": 1,
      "EditorId": 1,
      "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
      "Attachments": false,
      "GUID": "c93d9db6-efd8-4b49-9024-f8cc30c0a48e"
    }, {
      "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
      "Id": 16,
      "ID": 16,
      "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
      "Title": "B",
      "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
      "Created": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
      "AuthorId": 1,
      "EditorId": 1,
      "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
      "Attachments": false,
      "GUID": "a023853c-e967-4db8-8414-a7c390dcc09a"
    }]
  }
}

var pagesSimulatedResponse = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
      "Title": "Home",
      "MainCategory": "A"
    }, {
      "Title": "ewrwe",
      "MainCategory": "A"
    }, {
      "Title": "tgtg",
      "MainCategory": "A"
    }, {
      "Title": "dsdfsfdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsd",
      "MainCategory": "A"
    }, {
      "Title": "jk",
      "MainCategory": "A"
    }, {
      "Title": "Cliff Curtis",
      "MainCategory": "B"
    }, {
      "Title": "Martin Henderson",
      "MainCategory": "B"
    }]
  }
}


$(document).ready(function() {

  function showMainCategoryData() {

    var mainCategories, pages;

    /*
    // Make nested ajax calls here, one for Main Categories, the other for Pages.
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      ...
      success: function(data) {

        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
          // store Main Categories data
          mainCategories = data.d.results;

          // call nested `Pages` ajax (only runs with Main Categories successful response)
          $.ajax({
            url: url,
            ...
            success: function(data) {
              if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
                // store Pages data
                pages = data.d.results;

                // display results
                displayResults();

              } else {
                console.log('Pages returned no data');
              }
            },
            error: function(data) {}
          });
        } else {
          console.log('MainCategories returned no data');
        }
      },
      error: function(data) {}
    }); 
    */

    function displayResults() {
      var results = "";
      var html = "<table class='mainCatTable'><th class='mainCatHdr'>Main Category</th><th class='mainCatHdr'>Pages</th>";

      //loop over Main Categories
      for (var catIdx = 0; catIdx < mainCategories.length; catIdx++) {

        var pageCount = 0;

        for (var pageIdx in pages) {
          if (pages[pageIdx].MainCategory == mainCategories[catIdx].Title)
            pageCount++;
        }

        html += "<tr><td class='padRight'>" + mainCategories[catIdx].GUID + "</td>" + "<td>" + pageCount + "</td></tr>";
      }

      $("#inserthere").append(html + "</table>");
    }

    /*************** emulation code only ***************/
    // emulate above ajax calls    
    function ajaxCatSuccess(data) {
      if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
        // store Main Categories data
        mainCategories = data.d.results;

        // emulate call to nested `Pages` ajax
        ajaxPageSuccess(pagesSimulatedResponse);

      } else {
        console.log('MainCategories returned no data');
      }
    }

    function ajaxPageSuccess(data) {
      if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
        // store Pages data
        pages = data.d.results;

        // display results
        displayResults();

      } else {
        console.log('Pages returned no data');
      }
    }

    // trigger first simulated ajax call

    ajaxCatSuccess(mainCategorySimulatedResponse)
    /************ end of emulate code ***************/

  }

  showMainCategoryData();

});
```

```css
.mainCatTable {
  margin-left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  border: 3px solid
}

.mainCatHdr {
  text-align: left
}

.padRight {
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="inserthere"></div>
```

Comment: Note you can use `.append()` to insert html inside the target, instead of using `.after()`, which places it outside, and after the target element

Comment: If I were to improve it a little I'd pass the data as parameters to the `displayResults` function: `displayResults(mainCategories, pages)`. That way the data flow is more explicit.

Comment: @K Scandrett worked very well,, and now the performance have improved a lot.. thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe cleaning up your code will help? What I had in mind was get all the calls you need to make into one array and then map the api calls asynchronously then you'll get back all the pages faster. You need to make the the mapping of `getPages` happen in parallel.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getCurrentMainCategoryID() {

    var results = "";
    var html = "<table style='margin-left:20%;width:50%;boarder:3px solid'><th style='text-align:left'>Main Category</th><th></th><th style='text-align:left'>Pages</th>";
    var url = "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainCategory')/items?$select=Title";

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      async: false,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {

        var getTitle = result => result.Title;
        var results = data.d.results;
        var titles = results.map(getTitle);

        // not sure if it will be done in parallel
        // look for a library async.js vs parallel.js ???
        titles.map(title => getPages(title)) 

      }
    });

    $("#inserthere").after(html + "</table>");

    return results;
  });

  function getPages(title) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items??$select=Title,MainCategory&$filter=MainCategory eq " + "'" + title + "'",
      method: "GET",
      async: false,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
          html = html + "<tr><td>" + "</td>" + "<td>  </td><td>" + data.d.results.length + "</td></tr>";
        }
      }
    });
  }

  getCurrentMainCategoryID();
});
</script>
```

if you want to group elements into an array of objects just update your 2nd ajax call to create an object of the data and in the first one map over the mainCat's to create an array of desired grouping:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  function getCurrentMainCategoryID() {

    var grouped;
    var html = "<table style='margin-left:20%;width:50%;boarder:3px solid'><th style='text-align:left'>Main Category</th><th></th><th style='text-align:left'>Pages</th>";
    var url = "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainCategory')/items?$select=Title";

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      method: "GET",
      async: false,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var getTitle = result => result.Title;
        var results = data.d.results;
        var titles = results.map(getTitle);

        grouped = titles.map(title => {
          return {title: title, results: getPages(title)}
        });

        console.log(grouped);
      }
    });

    $("#inserthere").after(html + "</table>");

    return grouped;
  });

  function getPages(title) {

    var resultsObject;

    $.ajax({
      url: "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items??$select=Title,MainCategory&$filter=MainCategory eq " + "'" + title + "'",
      method: "GET",
      async: false,
      headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
      },
      success: function(data) {
        resultsObject = {
          pages: data.d.results,
          length: data.d.results.length
        }
      }
    });

    return resultsObject;
  }

  getCurrentMainCategoryID();
});
```

## sample grouping

```
[
  {
    title: _,
    results: {
      pages: [...],
      length: n
    }
  }, {
    title: _,
    results: {
      pages: [...],
      length: n
    }
  },
]
```

If you get all the data back in one call you can query for `mainCategories` and group.

## sample code for grouping

```js
function getMainCat(data, cat) {
  let grouped = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    let selection = Object.keys(item).reduce((acc, key) => {

      let results = item[key].results;
      let pages = results.filter(result => result["MainCategory"] == cat);

      let select = {
        title: key,
        results: {
          pages: pages,
          length: pages.length
        }
      }

      return acc.concat(select);
    }, []);

    return acc.concat(selection);
  }, []);

  return grouped;
}

let data = [
  {
    "d": {
      "results": [
        {
          "Title": "Home",
          "MainCategory": "A"
        }, {
          "Title": "ewrwe",
          "MainCategory": "A"
        }, {
          "Title": "tgtg",
          "MainCategory": "A"
        }, {
          "Title": "dsdfsfdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsd",
          "MainCategory": "A"
        }, {
          "Title": "jk",
          "MainCategory": "B"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]

console.log("searching A: ");
console.log(getMainCat(data, 'A'));
console.log("searching B: ");
console.log(getMainCat(data, 'B'));
console.log("searching C: ");
console.log(getMainCat(data, 'C'));
```

That's a suggestion overall I like how this code cleans up !

Comment: but i think still in your code a separate api call will be initiated for each maincategory is this correct ? so still the getPages() function will be called for each maincategory.. so this will not fix the performance issue i am facing

Comment: @johnG yup i do believe you are right, I'm not entirely sure how to do it but theres a way to make the `map` happen in parallel you should look into that

Comment: so you mean in your code the titles.forEach(title => getPages(title)); will not cause the call to happen in parallel ??

Comment: @johnG no it happenns one after the other. Maybe look into [this](https://parallel.js.org/)

Comment: but my question is not about doing parallel requests (which might also have performance drawbacks).. but i was asking if i can get all the pages' Title and maincategories.. then do the grouping inside the javascript.. so in this case i will be only doing 2 api calls; one to get all the main categories, the other call to get all the pages.. then inside the script itself i can group the pages according to the maincategories and count the result for each maincategory without having to do additional api calls ,, is this possible ?

Comment: @johnG if when you say you group do you mean create an array of objects that hold all that data for you? `{mainCat: { pages: [....], length: n } } ` ?

Comment: yes something similar to this... so i can have all the pages inside a temp variable (array) then to group the array by its maincategory.. so after the grouping i will have the data i need that category A have 10 pages, category B have 100 pages , etc.. then i can loop through the main category items and for each item to get its related count from the array..

Comment: @johnG I updated the code this should give you an array of those grouped objects

Comment: thanks for your edit.. but inside your updated code will it cause the `function getPages(title)` function to be called only one time? or still the `function getPages(title)V will be called separately for each main category item?? can u advice ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137247/discussion-between-jonathan-portorreal-and-john-g).

Answer (score 1):

**Some suggestions :**

- Instead of calling `Pages` API call every time based on the `mainCategory` API call response. You can call both the API's(mainCategory & pages) only once to increase the performance of the application.
- You can call both the API's asynchronously to get the data on page load.

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function getCurrentMainCategoryID() {
  var url = "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainCategory')/items?$select=Title";
  $.ajax({
    url: url,
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
    },
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
        var mainCategoriesData = data.d.results;
        getPagesData();
      } else {
        console.log('MainCategories returned no data');
      }

      function getPagesData() {
        var url = "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items";
        $.ajax({
          url: url,
          method: "GET",
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose"
          },
          success: function(data) {
            if (data.d.results.length > 0) {
              var pagesData = data.d.results;
            } else {
            console.log('Pages returned no data');
            }
          }
      });
      }
    }
  });
  ```

Now, you have both `pages` data and `main category` data.

```
var mainCategoriesData = [
            {                    
                "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 15,
                "ID": 15,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
                "Title": "A",
                "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
                "Created": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
                "AuthorId": 1,
                "EditorId": 1,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "GUID": "c93d9db6-efd8-4b49-9024-f8cc30c0a48e"
            },
            {
                 "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 16,
                "ID": 16,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
                "Title": "B",
                "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
                "Created": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
                "AuthorId": 1,
                "EditorId": 1,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "GUID": "a023853c-e967-4db8-8414-a7c390dcc09a"
            }];

var pagesData = [
            {    
                "Title": "Home",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "ewrwe",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "tgtg",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "dsdfsfdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsd",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "jk",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            }
        ];
```

Using [**for ... in**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop you can iterate the response and get the `page counts` as per the `main category`.

**DEMO**

```js
var mainCategoriesData = [
            {                    
                "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 15,
                "ID": 15,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
                "Title": "A",
                "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
                "Created": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
                "AuthorId": 1,
                "EditorId": 1,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "GUID": "c93d9db6-efd8-4b49-9024-f8cc30c0a48e"
            },
            {
                 "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
                "Id": 16,
                "ID": 16,
                "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
                "Title": "B",
                "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
                "Created": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
                "AuthorId": 1,
                "EditorId": 1,
                "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
                "Attachments": false,
                "GUID": "a023853c-e967-4db8-8414-a7c390dcc09a"
            }];

var pagesData = [
            {    
                "Title": "Home",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "ewrwe",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "dkjfkdf",
                "MainCategory": "B"
            },            
            {    
                "Title": "tgtg",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "dsdfsfdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsd",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            },
            {    
                "Title": "slkfjrel",
                "MainCategory": "B"
            },            
            {    
                "Title": "jk",
                "MainCategory": "A"
            }
        ];   
        
var resArr = [];  
var count = 1;
for (var i in mainCategoriesData) {
  for (var j in pagesData) {
    if(pagesData[j].MainCategory == mainCategoriesData[i].Title) {
      mainCategoriesData[i].pagesCount = count++;
    }
  }
  count = 1;
  resArr.push({
    "Main Category": mainCategoriesData[i].Title,
    "PagesCount": mainCategoriesData[i].pagesCount
  })
}        

console.log(resArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `jQuery.getJSON()` it will return the object already parsed. You only need two ajax calls. Modify the url and remove the filter for category you want to get all pages at one call.

```
var results = [];
var html = "<table style='margin-left:20%;width:50%;boarder:3px solid'><th style='text-align:left'>Main Category</th><th></th><th style='text-align:left'>Pages</th>";

$.getJSON( "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('MainCategory')/items?$select=Title")
  .done(function( categories ) {
    var mainCategoryResults = categories.d.results;
    $.getJSON( "/test/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('pages')/items?$select=Title,MainCategory")
      .done(function( pages ) {
        var pageResults = pages.d.results;      
        $(mainCategoryResults).each(function(k,v){
            var i=0;
            $(pageResults).each(function(key,val){
                if(v['Title'] === val['MainCategory']){
                    i++;
                }
            });
        results.push([v.Title,i]);
        });       
      })
      .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
        var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
        console.log( "Pages Request Failed: " + err );
    });     
  })
  .fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
    var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
    console.log( "Categories Request Failed: " + err );
});
```

You can test the double `each()` loop that creates the result in the below snippet.

```js
var a = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 15,
        "ID": 15,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
        "Title": "A",
        "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
        "Created": "2017-03-01T12:08:35Z",
        "AuthorId": 1,
        "EditorId": 1,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "c93d9db6-efd8-4b49-9024-f8cc30c0a48e"
      },
      {
        "FileSystemObjectType": 0,
        "Id": 16,
        "ID": 16,
        "ContentTypeId": "0x010006DDBDD3BDC9914B92E911733F2A56E1",
        "Title": "B",
        "Modified": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
        "Created": "2017-03-01T12:10:27Z",
        "AuthorId": 1,
        "EditorId": 1,
        "OData__UIVersionString": "1.0",
        "Attachments": false,
        "GUID": "a023853c-e967-4db8-8414-a7c390dcc09a"
      }
    ]
  }
};
var b = {
  "d": {
    "results": [{
        "Title": "Home",
        "MainCategory": "A"
      },
      {
        "Title": "ewrwe",
        "MainCategory": "A"
      },
      {
        "Title": "tgtg",
        "MainCategory": "A"
      },
      {
        "Title": "dsdfsfdfsdfsdfsdfsdsdfsd",
        "MainCategory": "A"
      },
      {
        "Title": "jk",
        "MainCategory": "A"
      }
    ]
  }
};
var c = [];
$(a.d.results).each(function(k, v) {
  var i = 0;
  $(b.d.results).each(function(key, val) {
    if (v['Title'] === val['MainCategory']) {
      i++;
    }
  });
  c.push([v.Title, i]);
});
console.log(c);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```